# How do I use the value of a JavaScript variable in a module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I need to use the value of a JavaScript variable in a module.
For example, I am getting a `city = 'delhi'` in a JavaScript file, and I need to use this value in a module showing a form.

Answer (score 0):

You could send that value to a callback function in your .module file using AJAX, an example to do that stuff in forms see that tutorial [Ajaxify form fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1408994)

And you could send any value to js variable see [sending-a-javascript-variable-to-drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32180/sending-a-javascript-variable-to-drupal?rq=1)